# Existence of transfer function

Tags: control-systems

This is my system.

[image: Continuos system with sampler]

Is there a way to find a transfer function? I can’t help the YR(s) going inside B(s) without being sampled, and I think this is the problem. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to determine an expression for the samplers. Normally i would think that those are A/D converters, but  they give $A(s)$ and in the variable $s$ it is implied (sort of) that is the laplace transform, and laplace transforms are used for continuos time systems, so the samplers T could also be just converting the signal into a piecewise constant signal, and that is a non linear operation.

Please try to clarify this, and then we will be able to help you more easily.

Comment: Yes they are A/D cards. A(s) is a lever, so yeah it’s continuos. I though that converting to piecewise was linear :/ maybe i can move those around since they have negligible delay